# sweetAlert toast is showing behind the navbar

Tags: vuejs2, sweetalert2

[image]

SweetAlert2's toast floated behind the navbar , I tried to solve it with z-index but it doesn't work , I'm using sweetAlert2 with vuejs
and that's how I use it :-

```
showSuccessAlert() {
        Toast.fire({
            icon: 'success',
            title: 'Product added successfully to cart',
        })
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

have you tried changing the z-index of sweetalert?

```
Toast.fire({
  customClass: {
    container: 'my-swal'
  },
  icon: 'success',
  title: 'Product added successfully to cart',
})
```

and in css file add this

```
.my-swal {
  z-index: 99999;
}
```

also please check this link
https://github.com/sweetalert2/sweetalert2/issues/665

Comment: thank u for your answer but it still the same ...

Comment: can you check the DOM of your site and see if the sweetalert modal is nested under the nav?
if so try changing the target
Toast.fire({
            target: document.getElementById('form-modal'),

Comment: it's nested above the nav